# Loading data during onCreate() via AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-room, weak-references, oncreate

I'm trying to load data during `onCreate` (also tried during `onStart`) via AsyncTask from a `Room` database. The thing is, I'm passing the context to the `AsyncTask` via a `WeakReference` and, sometimes (one out of four times) the context becomes null on the `onPostExecute`, even though the task finishes almost instantly (it's a small database).

I don't know which is the correct approach to load data via `AsyncTask` on the `onCreate` method without risking the context to become null so quick - I know it has to be done via WeakReference in order to avoid memory leaks, but I think the activity gets recreated for some reason sometimes so quickly that the task can't post the results to the original context and the data doesn't show up in the `Activity`.

Any ideas what is the correct way to handle this, given the fact the task finishes almost instantly, but it's a requirement of the `Room` library to do it via another thread (an also improves performance and responsiveness)?

So just for the sake of clearness, I'm trying to access the context this way:

```
public MyTask(ActivityListener listener) {
    mWeakContext = new WeakReference(listener);
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    AcitivtyListener aListener = mWeakContext.get();
    if (aListener != null) aListener.refresh(data);
}
```

The `ActivityListener` interface is implemented anonymously on the call to `new MyTask(new ActivityListener() { ... });`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think context becoming null means activity was re-created, but it seems unlikely to happen as I imagine its so fast you couldn't rotate the phone faster than the database operation

Indirect answer to this question would simply be: do not use `AsyncTask` at all, use `ViewModel` and `LiveData` - they are part of the architecture thing from google as well as `Room` that you are using

To put it short these two components will solve issues with lifecycle management/context leaking and also sending results to correct `Activity` instance

See documentation on LiveData and ViewModel: [livedata](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) [viewmodel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check if this solves the issue (it's not trivial) and consider validating the answer tomorrow! Cheers

Comment: Yeah its not trivial but if you invest your time I think youll see that this approach is better and maybe also if you look into lets say RxJava you will leave AsyncTasks completely, love to hear on your progress